# Pointer and integer comparison warning C

Tags: c, string

With –l for largest and –s for smallest number, if the user enters an invalid option, the program should display an error message. I have to code functioning.

The current error is comparison of pointer and integer within the first and second if() statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *numbers[])
{
        //variables needed
        int i,temp,max,min;

        //find largest (-1)
        if (!(strcmp(numbers[1],"-1")))
        {
            max = atoi(numbers[2]);
            for (i=2;i<argc;i++)
            {
                    if(numbers[i] >= 'a' && numbers[i] <= 'z')
                    {
                            printf("bad input");
                    }
                    else if(numbers[i] >= 'A' && numbers[i] <= 'Z')
                    {
                            printf("bad input");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            temp = atoi(numbers[i]);
                            if (max<temp)
                            {
                                    max = temp;
                            }
                    }
            }
            //output after loop
            printf("\nThe largest number is %d\n",max);

    }
    else if (!(strcmp(numbers[1],"-s")))
    {
            min = atoi(numbers[2]);
            for (i=2;i<argc;i++)
            {
                    temp = atoi(numbers[i]);
                    if (min>temp)
                    {
                            min = temp;
                    }
            }
            printf("\nThe smallest number is %d\n",min);
    }
    else
    {


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what were you trying to achieve by `numbers[i] >= 'a'` comparison? What is it supposed to compare with what?

Answer (score 2):

> char *numbers[]

Your `numbers` is an array of pointer to char (note that `[]` has higher precedence than `*` - and so that's why it's array to pointer), so the comparision `if(numbers[i] >= 'a' && numbers[i] <= 'z')` doesn't make sense.

What you would need is `if(numbers[i][0] >= 'a' && numbers[i][0] <= 'z')`. Also for the following condition, it should be `if(numbers[i][0] >= 'A' && numbers[i][0] <= 'Z')`. Because `char *numbers[]` is array of pointer to char, so `numbers[i]` is pointer to char, and so the first character can be accessed via `numbers[i][0]`

Answer (score 1):

numbers [i] is a pointer. You cannot compare numbers [i] with a single character.

Comment: your current compiler errors come from passing pointer of characters to character. to solve the compiler errors at first step: rename all of numbers[x] to numbers[x][0] within the if enclosure.